# Am I using the sharethis API correctly?

Tags: sharethis

I have icons (custom branded facebook, twitter, pinterest etc.) on a website and I would like it to be easy for visitors to talk about blogposts on these various social media.

To do so, I have created a server-side function that outputs links that look like this:

```
<a target="_blank" href=http://rest.sharethis.com/share/sharer.php?destination=facebook&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fsite.mydevelopmentserver.com&amp;title=postname&amp;pub_key=123456&amp;access_key=123456"/>FACEBOOK LINK</a>
```

with equivalent links for the other social media links.

I do not load any sharethis scripts or interact with the sharethis api in any other way on my site, and this method seems to be working fine (the jury is still out on analytics)

My questions are:

a. Is there anything wrong with using sharethis in this way?

b.Is there a better way to do this that does not require me to have my access key visible in my links?

Answer (score 4):

I think the answer to my questions are:

a. Yes, there is something wrong with using sharethis in this manner.  Your access key will be visible to everyone.

b. Yes, there is a better way to do this.  There is no need to access the API directly at all to customize your sharethis buttons.  Just insert the normal sharethis script that you can generate here: http://sharethis.com/publishers/get-sharing-tools, then change the buttons' classes to st_[service]_custom (where service is the service you would like to access).

That is, put I put this in my header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">stLight.options({publisher: "1234"});</script>
```

and this in the body:

```
<span class="st_pinterest_custom">Pinterest</span>
<span class="st_twitter_custom">Twitter</span>
<span class="st_facebook_custom">Facebook</span>
<span class="st_googleplus_custom">Google</span>
<span class="st_stumbleupon_custom">Stumble</span>
```

Then I just style the buttons using my own CSS.

Works like a charm, thanks sharethis!

Also, if anybody needs general help making things more complicated than they need to be, ask me -- I can do it for you in a jiffy!

Answer (score 0):

I think the answers to my questions are:

a. Yes, there is something wrong with using sharethis in this manner.  My access key will be visible to everyone.

b. Yes, there is a better way to do this.  There is no need to access the API directly at all to customize your sharethis buttons.  Just insert the normal sharethis script that you can generate here: http://sharethis.com/publishers/get-sharing-tools, then change the buttons' classes to st_[service]_custom (where service is the service you would like to access).

That is, put I put this in my header: 
    
    stLight.options({publisher: "1234"});

and this in the body:
    Pinterest
    Twitter
    Facebook
    Google
    Stumble

Comment: This is almost exactly the same as the beginning of your [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12983675/5827958).  Since it is just an addition to that answer, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/12983675/edit) that information into the other answer and then delete this one.